# Parsing Complex JSON File into CSV [Magic the Gathering]

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, parsing, export-to-csv

I'm trying to parse out a JSON file containing information for all Magic the Gathering cards into a flat csv file. Just trying to get some practice in manipulating data sets with different data types - the source json file can be found here (click "All Sets" to download JSON file): https://mtgjson.com/

Additional documentation (i.e., all fields in the above JSON file) can be found in the documentation tab on the above site.

The way the JSON file is structured is there are >200 sets, and there are many cards for each set. I have the below code which successfully writes out all the necessary card level information for each card in a given set (things like mana cost, card name, card colors, etc.) into a CSV file. However, I would also like to write out info to the CSV that is one level above card level information - namely, set level information. These are things like "name", "code", ... "booster" as you can see in following screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0koMk.jpg. Ideally any set level information would be the first few columns in the CSV file, then followed by card level information. Basically a "flat" type of CSV file.

```
import json
import csv

sets = ['UNH','UGL','pWOS','pWOR','pWCQ','pSUS','pSUM','pREL','pPRO','pPRE','pPOD','pMPR','pMGD','pMEI','pLPA','pLGM','pJGP','pHHO','pWPN','pGTW','pGRU','pGPX','pFNM','pELP','pDRC','pCMP','pCEL','pARL','pALP','p2HG','p15A','PD3','PD2','H09','PTK','POR','PO2','PCA','PC2','HOP','VMA','MMA','MM3','MM2','MED','ME4','ME3','ME2','EMA','MPS_AKH','MPS','EXP','V16','V15','V14','V13','V12','V11','V10','V09','DRB','EVG','DDS','DDR','DDQ','DDP','DDO','DDN','DDM','DDL','DDK','DDJ','DDI','DDH','DDG','DDF','DDE','DDD','DDC','DD3_JVC','DD3_GVL','DD3_EVG','DD3_DVD','DD2','CNS','CN2','CMD','CMA','CM1','C17','C16','C15','C14','C13','CEI','CED','E01','ARC','ZEN','WWK','WTH','W17','W16','VIS','VAN','USG','ULG','UDS','TSP','TSB','TPR','TOR','TMP','THS','STH','SOM','SOK','SOI','SHM','SCG','S99','S00','RTR','RQS','ROE','RAV','PLS','PLC','PCY','ORI','ONS','OGW','ODY','NPH','NMS','MRD','MOR','MMQ','MIR','MGB','MD1','MBS','M15','M14','M13','M12','M11','M10','LRW','LGN','LEG','LEB','LEA','KTK','KLD','JUD','JOU','ITP','ISD','INV','ICE','HOU','HML','GTC','GPT','FUT','FRF_UGIN','FRF','FEM','EXO','EVE','EMN','DTK','DST','DRK','DPA','DKM','DKA','DIS','DGM','CST','CSP','CP3','CP2','CP1','CON','CHR','CHK','BTD','BRB','BOK','BNG','BFZ','AVR','ATQ','ATH','ARN','ARB','APC','ALL','ALA','AKH','AER','9ED','8ED','7ED','6ED','5ED','5DN','4ED','3ED','2ED','10E']

with open('AllSets.json', encoding = 'utf8') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

    header = ['id', 'layout', 'name', 'names', 'manaCost', 'cmc', 'colors', 'colorIdentity', 'type', 'superTypes', 'types', 'subtypes', 'rarity', 'text', 'flavor', 'artist', 'number', 'power', 'toughness', 'loyalty', 'multiverseid', 'variations', 'imageName', 'watermark', 'border', 'timeshifted', 'hand', 'life', 'reserved', 'releaseDate', 'starter', 'mciNumber']

    # create the csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(open('testData.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8'), fieldnames = header, extrasaction='ignore')

    csvwriter.writeheader()

    for set in sets:

        set_data = json_data[set]['cards']

        for card in set_data:

            csvwriter.writerow(card)
```

I'm thinking that in the `for card in set_data` loop we need code that writes out set level information to the CSV file on a row by row basis. I tried something like `csvwriter.writerow(set['code'])` for the set's specific code field, but unfortunately this yields a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error. Would really appreciate any advice!

Comment: The reason the `csvwriter.writerow(set['code'])` threw the error is because that syntax thinks you are trying to index the string set represents from your list. In order to access the `code` part of the set's dictionary, you would need to use `json_data[set]['code']` like you did in the code above to access the `'cards'` nested dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the response - inserting code to access set level information in each set's dictionary: `code = json_data[set]['code']` does work and successfully prints to the console. If I try something like `csvwriter.writerow(code)` in the `for card in set_data` for loop though, it still throws an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` error. Just not sure of correct syntax to get the csvwriter to write set level info to the CSV file

Comment: That's because you are using a DictWriter object to write to your CSV file it's expecting a dictionary as the input before it writes and you are passing it a string with `json_data[set]['code']`.  The best way to do this I think would be to get your data structure set in either another dictionary or list format and then write that to the csv so all your inputs are the same to the csvwriter object.  Maybe set it up in a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Okay thanks - I'm sure there some way of getting it to work with the existing data structure though without having to port it into a pandas dataframe. Seems like a relatively common problem, but I haven't been able to find much support material.

Comment: No you don't have to use Pandas I was just offering that as a suggestion but if you want to use Dictwriter you will need to create a new dictionary for each line you want to write that has the info needed in a `key:value` format inside of it instead of just a string.  You're changing the data structure from hierarchical to flat I would suggest searching for problems like that and you'll find plenty of help.

Comment: Thanks Matthew - that's helpful

Comment: Please answer, wait the mandatory two days, and accept the answer.